# Issues with subsetting data.frame with daterange for shiny ggplot output

Tags: r, date, dataframe, shiny, subset

I am trying to create a R app using `shiny`. It consists of a `sliderInput` which allows user to select a daterange (minimum and maximum date) for subsetting the data which will be plotted as a ggplot bar graph.

I am facing issues with getting the input values to subset the data.frame which will then be used to plot on the bar graph. I have my subsetting codes via the R control, and it is generating correct data, however my attempt to use the input values as the limiting factor is running me with issues when I attempt to run it on the app.

my codes is as follow:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

#define shiny UI
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Life Span"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("days",

              "Duration:",
              min = start,
              max = last,
              value = c(start,last),
              timeFormat = "%F %T")
    ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("timeline")
  )
 )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    #here i create function to scope data
    getDataSubSet <- function(dataFrame, column2Filter, rangeStart, rangeEnd){
        rangeStart1<-strptime(rangeStart,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        rangeEnd1<-strptime(rangeEnd,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        dataFrame[dataFrame[column2Filter] >= rangeStart1 & dataFrame[column2Filter] <= rangeEnd1,]
    }


    output$timeline <- renderPlot({
        #to create reactive data....
        Candy_Sales_Working <- reactive({
            getDataSubSet(Candy_Sales, "Sales_date", input$days[1], input$days[2])
        })
        ggplot(Candy_Sales_Working(), aes(Candy_Sales_Working()[candyType])) + 
            geom_bar(stat="count")

    })
})
```

global.R

```
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user = "user", password = "pw", dbname = "candy", 
                 host = "candy.com", port = ....)
Candy_Sales = dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = "Select * from candy_sales")
Candy_Sales <- transform(Tape_Span,
Sales_Date = as.POSIXlt(strptime(Sales_Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
Candy_Sales_Working <- Candy_Sales
start = strptime(min(Candy_Sales$Sales_Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
last = strptime(max(Candy_Sales$Sales_Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
candy_types = unique(Candy_Sales$candyType)
```

error stated was **comparison of these types is not implemented**

Comment: sorry i forgotten to stat the error, it is "comparison of these types is not implemented"

Comment: In the `ggplot` line, it seems that it should be `ggplot(Tape_Span_Working(), aes...`

Comment: It is a typo when transferring the code here, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: But you also have `Candy_Span_Working` elsewhere (at the beginning of `server.R` and also in `global.R`. Should probably choose different names

Comment: noted, you can probably ignore the one in server.R, it was there when my train of thoughts was to implement the sliderInput to affect the dataset retrieved from database directly; hence not needing to hold it on R. But that would be my next phase.

Comment: i apologise for having so much typo, shall do my checking before i post my question next time

Comment: btw, the issue is still not resolved...

Comment: You still have errors in your code so I am not sure which one is causing it. `Candy_Sales_Working[candyType]` should be `Candy_Sales_Working()[candyType]`

Comment: It still throws me the same error after changing it to Candy_Sales_Working()[candyType]

Comment: I was narrowing my error to 

  `getDataSubSet <- function(dataFrame, column2Filter, rangeStart, rangeEnd){
        rangeStart1<-strptime(rangeStart,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        rangeEnd1<-strptime(rangeEnd,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        dataFrame[dataFrame[column2Filter] >= rangeStart1 & dataFrame[column2Filter] <= rangeEnd1,]
    }`

Comment: But it worked fine as standalone...

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, it was due to `dataFrame[column2Filter]` should be written as `dataFrame[[column2Filter]]` instead

```
 dataFrame[dataFrame[[column2Filter]] >= rangeStart1 & dataFrame[[column2Filter]] <= rangeEnd1,]
```